# How can I apply a style to all TextBlock and TextBox elements that exist in all ItemsControl elements?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I need to define a global style for all `TextBlock` and `TextBox` that exist within `ItemsControl` elements.

I need all the `TextBlock` elements to have a Width of 100 and Left aligned, and the `TextBox` elements to have a width of 50 and to be Right aligned.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your "that exist within ItemsControl elements" but if you are talking about your ItemsTemplate it should work like this

```
<Style x:Key="myTextBoxStyle">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="myTextBlockStyle">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
</Style>

<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource myTextBlockStyle}"/>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource myTextBoxStyle}"/>
            <Grid>
        <DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This will display all items in your ItemsControl with a textbox which uses your myTextBoxStyle and your textblock with the myTextBlockStyle.

Answer (score 2):

you can declare the style inside the ItemsControl.Resources as well

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="TxtBlk1" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="red"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="56"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
            </Style>

        </ItemsControl.Resources>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource TxtBlk1}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```